# What is causing my C string function for generating a complementary DNA sequence to fail at positions other than 0?

Tags: c, string, function

I wanted to write a function that took a DNA sequence and outputed the complimentary sequence. For example change the sequence ATGC to TACG. The function I have written works for this. However, I wanted the function to only make the complimentry sequence at the position I define. But the function I wrote doesnt work if I pass anything other than 0 for the position.

I am not sure what the problem is becuase I am not getting a complier error or segementation fault.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void compliment(string seq, string comp_seq, int pos, int lenght);

int main(void)
{
    string DNA_seq = get_string("Input: ");

    char compliment_DNA_seq[strlen(DNA_seq) + 1];

    compliment(DNA_seq, compliment_DNA_seq, 0, 22);

    printf("\n%s\n%s\n\n", DNA_seq, compliment_DNA_seq);
}

void compliment(string seq, string comp_seq, int pos, int lenght)
{
    int j = lenght;
    for (int i = pos; j > 0; i++, j--)
    {
        if (seq[i] == 65)
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 84;
        }
        else if (seq[i] == 67)
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 71;
        }
        else if (seq[i] == 71)
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 67;
        }
        else
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 65;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably copy the data from *before* the start point unchanged into the result string.

Comment: And use character literals like `'A'` instead of magic numbers. More readable, easier to understand, and works if someone finds an EBCDIC system to run your code on...

Comment: Oh, and length, not lenght.

Comment: You are not copying the substring till `pos` from `DNA_seq` to `compliment_DNA_seq`.

Comment: I believe the "complimentary" sequence for DNA, for any who aren't familiar, is to replace any occurrence of `A` with `T`, replace any `T` with `A`, replace any `C` with `G` and replace any `G` with `C`.  (Because adenine pairs with thymine, and cytosine pairs with guanine)

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the problem is to copy the entire `DNA_seq` into `complimentary_DNA_seq` to start with, using `strcpy()`. One has to be careful while using `strcpy()`: the destination buffer should be greater than or equal to the source buffer, after considering the terminating null character also. Note: Just assigning `DNA_seq` to `complimentary_DNA_seq` by doing `string complimentary_DNA_seq = DNA_seq` leads to a shallow copy. Any change to `complimentary_DNA_seq` also changes `DNA_seq`.

Also, as Shawn says in a comment, manipulating the characters of the string directly using character literals is preferable to using the ASCII values.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int compliment(string seq, string comp_seq, int pos, int length);

int main(void)
{
    string DNA_seq = get_string("Input: ");

    char compliment_DNA_seq[strlen(DNA_seq) + 1];
    // Copy the original sequence into the complimentary sequence
    // Note: string compliment_DNA_seq = DNA_seq; leads to a shallow copy.
    // We want a deep copy.
    strcpy(compliment_DNA_seq, DNA_seq);

    int error_flag = compliment(DNA_seq, compliment_DNA_seq, 2, 3);

    if (error_flag == -1) {
      return -1;
    }

    printf("\n%s\n%s\n\n", DNA_seq, compliment_DNA_seq);

    return 0;
}

// TODO: the function could be updated to receive only comp_seq
// Since, it already is a copy of seq.
int compliment(string seq, string comp_seq, int pos, int length)
{
    // Do some error handling
    if (pos >= strlen(seq)) {
        printf("Enter a position within the sequence.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pos + length > strlen(seq)) {
        printf("Trying to copy beyond the limit of the input sequence.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // compliment the characters in [pos, pos + length)
    int j = length;
    for (int i = pos; j > 0; i++, j--)
    {
        // manipulating the characters directly with
        // character literals.
        if (seq[i] == 'A')
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 'T';
        }
        else if (seq[i] == 'C')
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 'G';
        }
        else if (seq[i] == 'G')
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 'C';
        }
        else
        {
            comp_seq[i] = 'A';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```